# Issue injecting DAO to an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, rx-java2, android-room

I'm trying to integrate Room, dagger 2 and rxjava

> > io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: lateinit property userDao has not been initialized

I encounter the error above, **how do I init/access my DAO in a activity after injecting it into an activity ?**

My build.gradle

```
// --- Room --- //
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0-alpha1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha1"
// --- Room --- //

// --- dagger --- //
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1"

//implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
//kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
// --- dagger --- //

// --- RxJava2 --- //
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0"
// --- RxJava2 --- //
```

User.kt

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "email") val email: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "firstName") val first: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName") val last: String
)
```

UserDao.kt

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert
import android.arch.persistence.room.OnConflictStrategy
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query
import io.reactivex.Flowable

@Dao interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getUsers(): Flowable<List<User>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(user: User)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(users: List<User>)
}
```

AppDatabase.kt

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [(User::class)], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room
import android.content.Context
import com.singpost.prototype.sam.database.AppDatabase
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class AppModule(private val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppContext() = context

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "/data/data/com.lsy.prototype.sam/databases/userdb.db").build()

    @Provides
    fun providesUserDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase) = appDatabase.userDao()
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
...
import com.singpost.prototype.sam.database.User
import com.singpost.prototype.sam.database.UserDao
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
        ... {
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

@Inject lateinit var userDao: UserDao

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val user = User("e@mail.com", "Jack", "Potato")

        compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable { userDao.insert(user) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe())

    }
```

Comment: In the MainActivity, you are injecting UserDao, you can remove that as you are not using.

Comment: how do i call my Dao insert(user) method then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a component in order to create the graph:

```
@Component(modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()
}
```

Here ActivityBuilder is a module to map all our activities, then Dagger will know about our activities in compile time.

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Your application should extend DaggerApplication class (or implement HasActivityInjector) and override the `applicationInjector` method like this:

```
override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<App>  
    = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().create(this)
```

Finally the `MainActivity` should extends DaggerAppCompatActivity (or implement `HasSupportFragmentInjector`, check how to do it in this case) and everything should be injected.

Let me know if it works, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Component:

```
@Component(modules=[AppModule::class])
class AppComponent{
   inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

Then your Application class can call in `onCreate()`

```
appComponent=DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
```

Then your activity has to get the Component through a getter:

```
(application as MyApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
```

You can use the advice from Gonzalo Acosta for a arguably better setup of Android Injection but it is more complex than this minimal setup. Also read [this](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) for more on Android Injection.